# How to strip extra spaces when writing from dataframe to csv

Tags: export-to-csv, strip

Read in multiple sheets (6) from an xlsx file and created individual dataframes.  Want to write each one out to a pipe delimited csv.

ind_dim.to_csv (r'/mypath/ind_dim_out.csv', index = None, header=True, sep='|')

Currently outputs like this:
1|value1            |value2        |word1 word2 word3 etc.

**Want to strip trailing blanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion**

Include the method `.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip())` to your output string (prior to the `.to_csv()` call) to strip the right trailing blank from each field across the DataFrame. It would look like:

**Change:**

```
ind_dim.to_csv(r'/mypath/ind_dim_out.csv', index = None, header=True, sep='|')
```

**To:**

```
ind_dim.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip()).to_csv(r'/mypath/ind_dim_out.csv', index = None, header=True, sep='|')
```

It can be easily inserted to the output code string using '.' referencing. To handle multiple data types, we can **enforce the 'object'** dtype on import by including the argument `dtype='str'`:

```
ind_dim = pd.read_excel('testing_xlsx_nums.xlsx', header=0, index_col=0, sheet_name=None, dtype='str')
```

Or on the DataFrame itself by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype='str')
```

**Proof**

I did a mock-up where the .xlsx document has *5 sheets*, with each sheet having three columns: The first column with *all numbers except an empty cell in row 2*; the second column with *both a leading blank and a trailing blank on strings, an empty cell in row 3, and a number in row 4*; and the third column * with all strings having a leading blank, and an empty value in row 4*. Integer indexes and integer columns have been included. The text in each sheet is:

```
    0   1   2
0   11111    valueB1     valueC1
1        valueB2     valueC2
2   33333        valueC3
3   44444   44444   
4   55555    valueB5     valueC5
```

This code reads in our .xlsx `testing_xlsx_dtype.xlsx` to the DataFrame dictionary `ind_dim`.

Next, it loops through each *sheet* using a for loop to place the sheet name variable as a key to reference the individual sheet DataFrame. It applies the `.str.rstrip()` method to the entire sheet/DataFrame by passing the `lambda x: x.str.rstrip()` lambda function to the `.apply()` method called on the sheet/DataFrame.

Finally, it outputs the sheet/DataFrame as a .csv with the pipe delimiter using `.to_csv()` as seen in the OP post.

```
# reads xlsx in 
ind_dim = pd.read_excel('testing_xlsx_nums.xlsx', header=0, index_col=0, sheet_name=None, dtype='str')

# loops through sheets, applies rstrip(), output as csv '|' delimit
for sheet in ind_dim:
    ind_dim[sheet].apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip()).to_csv(sheet + '_ind_dim_out.csv', sep='|')
```

**Returns:**

```
|0|1|2
0|11111| valueB1| valueC1
1|| valueB2| valueC2
2|33333|| valueC3
3|44444|44444|
4|55555| valueB5| valueC5
```

**(Note our column 2 strings *no longer have the trailing space*).**

We can also reference each sheet using a loop that cycles through the dictionary items; the syntax would look like `for k, v in dict.items()` where `k` and `v` are the *key* and *value*:

```
# reads xlsx in 
ind_dim = pd.read_excel('testing_xlsx_nums.xlsx', header=0, index_col=0, sheet_name=None, dtype='str')

# loops through sheets, applies rstrip(), output as csv '|' delimit
for k, v in ind_dim.items():
    v.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip()).to_csv(k + '_ind_dim_out.csv', sep='|')
```

**Notes:**

We'll still need to apply the correct arguments for selecting/ignoring indexes and columns with the `header=` and `names=` parameters as needed. For these examples I just passed `=None` for simplicity.

The other methods that strip leading *and* leading & trailing spaces are: `.str.lstrip()` and `.str.strip()` respectively. They can also be applied to an entire DataFrame using the `.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())` lambda function passed to the `.apply()` method called on the DataFrame.

**Only 1 Column:** If we only wanted to strip from one column, we can call the `.str` methods directly on the column itself. For example, to strip leading & trailing spaces from a column named `column2` in DataFrame `df` we would write: `df.column2.str.strip()`.

**Data types not string:** When importing our data, pandas will *assume* data types for columns with a similar data type. We can override this by passing `dtype='str'` to the `pd.read_excel()` call when importing.

pandas 1.0.1 documentation (04/30/2020) on `pandas.read_excel`:

**"dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, default None**

*Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion."*

We can pass the argument `dtype='str'` when importing with `pd.read_excel.()` (*as seen above*). If we want to enforce a single data type on a DataFrame we are working with, we can set it equal to itself and pass it to `pd.DataFrame()` with the argument `dtype='str` like: `df = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype='str')`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Appreciate such quick response!.  I did not realize that there are some numerics in the sheet as well.  So I get an error,

AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index INDICATOR_KEY')

Comment: @Boppy Hi! I updated my answer to reflect using `dtype='str'` on import to force the `object` data type; if you already have the Frame within your environment I also commented on resolving that. Changing the dtype will impact any sort of calculations you're doing if you're processing things like `np.mean()` on the data, so care to process any number-required functions before enforcing the `object` dtype. Other than that, pandas will assume dtype on `pd.to_csv` and set everything back similar to what it inferred on import. Hope this helps!

Comment: While waiting on your very thorough response, I tried this on the output:
lambda x: x.str.rstrip() if type(x)==str else x which kept the error from occurring.  Output seems correct.  
Thanks so much!

Comment: Excellent! That’s a nice way of resolving the type issue as well; good job!

Comment: Hey @Boppy if this answer was useful or solved your question please do me a favor and mark it as useful or solution - I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Of course. I’m so new to this site. Don’t readily see the option. Help again 

Comment: :D There will be a green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer; you can click that!  Here's a thread on it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

The following trims left and right spaces fairly easily:

```
 if (!require(dplyr)) {
   install.packages("dplyr")
 }
 library(dplyr)

 if (!require(stringr)) {
   install.packages("stringr")
 }
 library(stringr)

 setwd("~/wherever/you/need/to/get/data")

 outputWithSpaces <- read.csv("CSVSpace.csv", header = FALSE)
 print(head(outputWithSpaces), quote=TRUE)

 #str_trim(string, side = c("both", "left", "right"))

 outputWithoutSpaces <- outputWithSpaces %>% mutate_all(str_trim)
 print(head(outputWithoutSpaces), quote=TRUE)
```

Starting Data:

```
                                  V1                           V2                          V3            V4
 1    "Something is interesting.   " "This is also Interesting. "                      "Not " "Intereting "
 2  "  Something with leading space"                  "  Leading" "  Spaces with many words."      " More."
 3 "  Leading and training Space.  "                   "  More  "  "  Leading and trailing. "  "  Spaces. "
```

Resulting:

```
                               V1                          V2                        V3           V4
 1    "Something is interesting." "This is also Interesting."                     "Not" "Intereting"
 2 "Something with leading space"                   "Leading" "Spaces with many words."      "More."
 3  "Leading and training Space."                      "More"   "Leading and trailing."    "Spaces."
```